# Create a sort index for millions of records

Tags: mongodb

I have an application that runs a MongoDB database. This database will store 5 million documents per user. The web application that uses this database will display a 5 thousand of these documents on a page at any given time and will be a selection of the 5 million. Each document must have a sort order (or rank) such that the web page will be able to allow the user to sort their 5 thousand records, by dragging items up.down as they see fit (a sortable list).

I have read articles about how [Trello uses a double-float](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10957165) decimal number to change the value of the sorted item in a list, but this seems to only allow for 50-odd worst-case sorts, so will not accommodate the large number of items in the users list. My questions is how do I do this?

Comment: 5 thousand documents in a page is a lot.

Comment: Yes, although they probably won't be in the page at once, i.e. some kind of infinite scroll implementation. Nevertheless, the ability to move item 4999 to position 1 is still a possibility (albeit a very rare occasion).